# Python: pyqt5 not playing video?

Tags: python, video, pyqt5

Using python, I am trying to open and play a mp4 file, but it is not working. Here is my Python code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    wgt_video = QVideoWidget()  # Video display widget
    wgt_video.show()
    player.setVideoOutput(wgt_video)  # widget for video output
    player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl()[0]))  # Select video file
    player.play()
    app.exec_()
```

But it is not  working. There is no error, but when I select the mp4 video file, it does not show up. The video simply will not load. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: Install https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm

Comment: I am confused, why do I have to install codec?

Comment: QtMultimedia is a wrapper of the native libraries of each OS, Qt does not implement anything about reading, writing or reproducing audios, videos, etc. In windows the native library does not provide the codecs for all types of formats so you must install them yourself obviously reading the licenses.